# Create a logger in .Net having Throttling mode functionality

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I have to create a Logger in .NET that should work in normal and throttling mode.

It should stop logging (means it should switch to throttle mode) when there are continuous error or same error because of some reason (say server is not up) because if say server is not up for many days multiple log files will eat lot of space in disk.

And it should return to normal mode when the contineous error or same error stops.

Can anybody help me with some logic on how to achieve this?  I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library for creating the logger.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library will not let you know that a failure has occurred.  It will swallow the exception.  If you have the errors special source configured it will write the LogEntry to the errors special source.

You can either write a custom trace listener which contains your logic or modify the block to contain your specialized logic.

I'm assuming you want to write a custom trace listener.

Given the above, I think you have 2 choices: in your custom trace listener perform pre-logging checks to verify some set of preconditions (server is up etc.) or in your custom trace listener perform post-logging checks against the errors special source.  For the latter, you would need to know the location and format of the errors special source and you would need to parse it to determine if your error condition was met (number of errors per minute or number of consecutive errors etc.).

Both solutions have drawbacks.

What about this: for the errors special source use a RollingFlatFileTraceListener set to overwrite thus limiting the size on disk (you can choose how big you want the file(s) to be)?  You could even potentially harvest the log information if required.  It seems like a win-win.